# How to store and access url in a list for back and forward web browser functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, browser

I am making a web browser, but I am not allowed to use the web browser class provided by .NET. I have managed to make all the basic functionality. However I am now working on the back and forward buttons. I have a list which stores url ( urls entered in the address bar). I would like to loop through these to take the user either forward or backward depending on the button pressed.

My code:

```
public partial class WebBrowser : Form
{
    public string url;
    public string addressText;
    private homeForm homeForm;
    private List <string> urlList = new List <string> ();
    public WebBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void navigateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addressText = urlBar.Text;
        webNavigate(addressText);
    }

    private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void forwardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void webNavigate(string urlbartext )
    {
        addressText = urlBar.Text;
        urlbartext = "http://" + addressText;
        urlList.Add(urlbartext);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlbartext);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream pageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pageStream, Encoding.Default);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        webDisplay.Text = s;
        reader.Dispose();
        pageStream.Dispose();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Question. How do I use my List to check the sites visited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of List, try using Queue.
One for previously visited url's and one for future url's.

So, upon initial load of your browser, both queues are empty.
As soon as user navigates to a url, this url is inserted to the previous queue. If user hits the Back button, that url is taken from the previous queue and inserted into future queue.

That way you can avoid using enumerators and know at all times where your user is.

Comment: But I need to implement a browser history functionality, would a queue suffice for that too? I'm kinda using List so that I can refer to it later for my history.

Comment: Yes, queue would suffice.